# Does Electron have MDI similar to WinForm MDI

Tags: electron, mdi

I've been trying to search this up, but I can't find the answer.

In WinForms you can make an MDI to create forms inside of, so that the MDI child windows cannot go outside of the MDI parent window. Does Electron have this feature or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Nope because a Browser window cant contain another browser window ... unless you using a movable div with an iframe element... You have 2 options one create a modal window with your content like I've done here

[image]

or you can open a new remote window sub in your main JS entry file

```
                const electron = require('electron');
            const url = require('url');
            const path = require('path');

            const {app,BrowserWindow,Menu,ipcMain}= electron;
            //SET env

            //process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

            let mainWindow;
            let addWindow;


            //listen for the app to be ready
            app.on('ready',function(){
            //creat the new mainWindow
            mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width:1200,
            height:1000,
            frame:false,
                webPreferences: {

                plugins: true,
                nodeIntegration: true
             //contextIsolation: true
              }


            });
            mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname,'index.html'),
            protocol:'file',
            slashes: true
            }));
            //close all winsows on close
            mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
              app.quit();

            });


            //build menu from mainMenuTemplate
            const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
            Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);


            });

            //handle add new sub window
            function createAddWindow()
            {
              //creat the new mainWindow
              addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width:200,
                height:200,
                title:'add shoping list item'
              });
              //load html into window
              addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
              pathname: path.join(__dirname,'addWindow.html'),
              protocol:'file',
              slashes: true
              }));

              //garbage collection Handle
              addWindow.on('close',function(){
                addWindow= null;
              });
            }

            //Catch Item:add from the subwindown and send to the main html
            ipcMain.on('item:add' , function(e, item){
              console.log(item);
              mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add' , item);
              addWindow.close();

            });



            //var remote = require('remote');
                //  var BrowserWindow = remote.require('mainWindow');

                 // function init() {
                 //      Mainwindow.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                 //           var lMainwindow = Mainwindow.getFocusedWindow();
                 //           lMainwindow.minimize();
                 //      });
                 //
                 //      Mainwindow.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                 //           var lMainwindow = Mainwindow.getFocusedWindow();
                 //           lMainwindow.maximize();
                 //      });
                 //
                 //      Mainwindow.getElementById("Close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                 //           var lMainwindow = Mainwindow.getFocusedWindow();
                 //           lMainwindow.close();
                 //      });
                 // };
                 //
                 //
                 //           init();







            //Creat the menu template
            const mainMenuTemplate =[
            {
              label:'File',
              submenu:[
                {label:'Add Item',
                click(){
                  createAddWindow();
                }
              },
                {
                  label:'Clear items',
                  click(){
                    mainWindow.webContents.send('item:clear');
                    console.log('clear click');
                  }

                },
                {
                  label:'Quit',
                accelerator:process.platform=='darwin'? 'Command+Q' :'Ctrl+Q',
                click(){
                  app.quit();
                }
              }
              ]
            },

            ];

            //disable Nasty security warnings
            delete process.env.ELECTRON_ENABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS;
            process.env.ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS = true;

            //if mac add empty object to the menu to get of the title electron
            if(process.platform == 'darwin'){
              mainMenuTemplate.unshift({});
            }

            //add dev tools if not in production
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
            {
              mainMenuTemplate.push({
            label:'Developer Tools',
            submenu :[
              {
                label:'toggle Dev Tools',
                accelerator:process.platform=='darwin'? 'Command+I' :'Ctrl+I',
                click(item , focusedWindow){
                  focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();

                }
              },{
            role:'reload',


              }
            ]

              })

            }
```

here is the electron reference to a new window object [Window Object Reference](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open)

electron basically gives you a windows app menu with the chrome browser window... Nothing else... everything inside the window you have to code with your web technologies like HTML CSS and JS

If you find something that wont work in a web page it wont work in electron